# splitting values based on values in a specific column

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a file that I would like to break up into multiple files with uniq values for the first column. For example, here is a file:

fileA.txt

```
1    Cat
1    Dog
1    Frog
2    Boy
2    Girl
3    Tree
3    Leaf
3    Branch
3    Trunk
```

I would like my output to look something like this:

file1.txt

```
1    Cat
2    Boy
3    Tree
```

file2.txt

```
1    Dog
2    Girl
3    Leaf
```

file3.txt

```
1    Frog
3    Branch
```

file4.txt

```
3    Trunk
```

If a value does not exist, I want it to be skipped. I have tried to search for similar situations to mine, but I've come up short. Does anyone have idea of how to do this?

Theoretically, this awk command should work: `awk '{print > "file" ++a[$1] ".txt"}' input`. However, I can't get it to work appropriately (most likely due to the fact that I work on a mac) Does anyone know of an alternative way?

Comment: @EdMorton that was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unparenthesized expression on the right side of output redirection is undefined behavior. Try `awk '{print > ("file" ++a[$1] ".txt")}' input`.

If having too many files open concurrently is an issue then get GNU awk, but if you cant:

```
$ ls
 fileA.txt

$ awk '{f="file" ++a[$1] ".txt"; print >> f; close(f)}' fileA.txt

$ ls
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt  file4.txt  fileA.txt

$ cat file1.txt
1    Cat
2    Boy
3    Tree
```

Comment: I've noticed that when I use this that I get an error though. `awk: file18.txt makes too many open files
 input record number 19, file input.txt
 source line number 1` Do you know if there is a way to close the files as I read through my actual file? Maybe `awk '{print >> ("file" ++a[$1] ".txt")}' input`?

Comment: @interstellar In AWK, `>` and `>>` are slightly different from shells such as bash. Both `print >` and `print >>` will append to the file every time that line is executed. The difference is what happens the first time the line is executed. The first time `print >` is executed, it will truncate the file to zero, then append to it (and every subsequent time).  `print >>` will append without truncating the the first time. You want AWK to create fresh output and not keep whatever garbage you had from before, so `>` is appropriate in @EdMorton's answer.

Comment: @interstellar of course, just call close(). If you use GNU awk you wont have this problem as it manages the file statuses internally. I edited my answer to show how to add a close().

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in Python:

```
from collections import Counter
fd_dict = {}
ind_counter = Counter()

with open('fileA.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        ind, _ = line.split()
        ind_counter[ind] += 1
        file_ind = ind_counter[ind]
        fd = (
            fd_dict[file_ind] if file_ind in fd_dict else
            fd_dict.setdefault(
                file_ind, 
                open('file{}.txt'.format(file_ind), 'w')))
        fd.write(line)

for fd in fd_dict.itervalues():
    fd.close()
```