# parse CSV, Group all rows containing string at 5th field, export each group of rows to file with filename <group>_someconstant.csv

Tags: bash, parsing, csv, awk, group-by

Need this in bash.

In a linux directory, I will have a CSV file.  Arbitrarily, this file will have 6 rows.

**Main_Export.csv**

```
1,2,3,4,8100_group1,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,8100_group1,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,3100_group2,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,3100_group2,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5400_group3,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5400_group3,6,7,8
```

- I need to parse this file's 5th field (first four chars only) and take each row with 8100 (for example) and put those rows in a new file.  Same with all other groups that exist, across the entire file.
- Each new file can only contain the rows for its group (one file with the rows for 8100, one file for the rows with 3100, etc.)
- Each filename needs to have that group# prepended to it.

The first four characters could be any numeric value, so I can't check these against a list - there are like 50 groups, and maintenance can't be done on this if a group # changes.

When parsing the fifth field, I only care about the first four characters

So we'd start with: `Main_Export.csv` and end up with four files:

- `Main_Export_$date.csv` (unchanged)
- `8100_filenameconstant_$date.csv`
- `3100_filenameconstant_$date.csv`
- `5400_filenameconstant_$date.csv`

I'm not sure the rules of the site.  If I have to try this for myself first and then post this.  I'll come back once I have an idea - but I'm at a total loss.  Reading up on awk right now.

Comment: I do not think bash is competent for this task because the request to group data according to 5th field, why not try to use Perl. read all those data to hash table, indexed by 5th field, then output to files is a routine procedure in Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood well your problem this is very easy...

You can just:

```
$ awk -F, '{fifth=substr($5, 1, 4) ; print > (fifth "_mysuffix.csv")}' file.cv
```

or just:

```
$ awk -F, '{print > (substr($5, 1, 4) "_mysuffix.csv")}' file.csv
```

And you will get several files like:

```
$ cat 3100_mysuffix.csv 
1,2,3,4,3100_group2,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,3100_group2,6,7,8
```

or...

```
$ cat 5400_mysuffix.csv 
1,2,3,4,5400_group3,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5400_group3,6,7,8
```

Comment: This question is similar to [this recent one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161896/splitting-values-based-on-values-in-a-specific-column).  If you encounter problems like "too many open files," see [@EdMorton's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161896/splitting-values-based-on-values-in-a-specific-column#answer-35162076) with an adjustment to `close()` the files.

Comment: This was perfect - I ended up adding the date to the filename, so it looks like this: 

awk -v newdate=`date +%Y%m%d_%k%M%S` -F, '{print > (substr($18, 1, 4) "_"newdate"_concur.csv")}' main_concur_20160202.csv

For some reason, today, i received "awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `-F,' for reading (No such file or directory)"  while using the exact same code as before.  Tried it 20 times and got the same error.  Then i looked at the man page for awk, came back, tried the EXACT SAME CODE, and it's working...

Comment: What if I have something like this:

1,2,3,4,8100_group1,6,7,8

1,2,3,4,8100_group2,6,7,8

and i want two files

8100_timestamp.csv
- 1,2,3,4,8100_group1,6,7,8

8100_timestamp1secondlater.csv?
- 1,2,3,4,8100_group2,6,7,8

I would need to group by the entire field, but only append the first four characters of that field to the filename.  Any more suggestions?  I don't understand how you can split the matching expression from what you're naming the file. @maruo